# How to toggle a class AND scroll to that class at the same time using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'm trying to toggle a class which will have a div slide in, but I also want to jump to the div at the same time. But I can't seem to find anything on YouTube or Google.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("The page successfully loaded");

$('#click').on('click', function(){

    $('#click').toggleClass('lol');
});

$('.anson').on('click', function() {

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 5000}, "slow");
})

$('#info').on('click', function(){
    $("#about").toggle(500).animate({scrollTop: 5004}, "slow");

});

});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12cofeqh/

Ignore the images that don't work, just click the broken image on the bottom, all the way on the far right. A div should pop up on the bottom, but it does not slide to it and I want it to slide/scroll down to it.

Comment: cant see any element with the id of click

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a callback function to toggle that will scroll to the section once toggle has completed executing. See the snippet below

```
$('#about').toggle(500, function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/3f3fvdee/

Answer (score 0):

hey hi brother this is what you want i made some changes in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("The page successfully loaded");

$('#click').on('click', function(){

    $('#click').toggleClass('lol');
});

$('#info').on('click', function() {

    $('html').animate({scrollTop: 5000}, "slow");
});

$('#info').on('click', function(){
    $("#about").toggle(500).animate({scrollTop: -200}, "slow");

});

 });
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12cofeqh/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the scroll function after your "show animation". Change JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("The page successfully loaded");

    $('#click').on('click', function(){

        $('#click').toggleClass('lol');
    });

    $('.anson').on('click', function() {

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 5000}, "slow");
    })

    $('#info').on('click', function(){
        $("#about").toggle(500);
        $("html").animate({scrollTop: 5004}, "slow");

    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12cofeqh/4/)